# How can I refresh a DataRow linked to a MS Access record that has been changed by another user in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I a multi user system based on a MS Access database, there is a possibility of DataRow instances not being concurrent if the database records to which they are referring to are changed by another user during the session of the application. This will lead to a DBConcurrencyException being thrown. However that is not the issue. What I want is to notify the user about the current/actual state of the DataRow when such exception is thrown and make the user confirm or cancel the update in progress.

For the above to work I need to be able to refresh the DataRow with concurrent data from the database without creating a new instance or in  another way alter the reference of the DataRow. How can I do this? I can't seem to find an obvious way of doing this task which I imagine is quite common.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad to be specifically answered, and it also raises a couple red flags (Access and multiple users is typically a recipe for trouble).

The software pattern you're applying is called [Active Record](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html).  I suggest you research it thorough to understand the usual use-cases, benefits, costs, and approaches to things like concurrency, locking, and updates.